# How to download the data underlying the graphs on Keepa.com?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools

For example, for this page https://keepa.com/#!product/1-B00005NUZN, I cannot find the data underlying the graphs using the developer tools in chrome browser. I was usually able to trace the data source in the network tab, but for this website it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess it's because they are transferred as binary data over a websocket http://i.imgur.com/8qVWVK1.png

Comment: @vegar Thanks! Is there any solution?

Comment: That I do not know..

Comment: Use Fiddler or similar MitM proxy. Fiddler has docs/tutorials that show how to intercept HTTPS (it's easy).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I have tried Fiddler. Now I can see the binary data in Hexview within Fiddler, but how to convert the binary data to recognisable format?

Comment: Googled up a [decoder](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/718660/debug-inspect-websocket-traffic-with-fiddler).

Comment: FYI. There's an open issue looking at improving the view of binary web socket data in DevTools. Hopefully soon you won't need Fiddler. https://codereview.chromium.org/2257963002/.  FYI 2. There's a WebSocket Monitor extension in FireFox that can also be used in meantime. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/websocket-monitor/

Comment: @wOxxOm Is the decoder a general one (like https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) or a special one that is designed by the website to make the decoding harder?

Comment: I haven't tried any. Decoder means binary format decoder, not crypto-decoder.

Comment: @GideonPyzer Thanks! With the extension I can now see the payload of binary data, such as "x]Á Â0@ÿ%ç ®Sû zÛ¥nqV»v$(â¿;ÑMñøÞ ¹«À$ÙbjèT/çi*×àVlÓþÆ|Ö+É¦3ÇîÅG`&ú (Òk0¡ó^·,û¶²`¦ ZUW ¹ìCÉá¿¹m,aøVhýdÙ¢÷H¼r,²åÅú»+6»¢¸£ë¯¸FÉïeâµ<ÙPãÀ#íõàO3mì",  but how to decode this?